# Traffic prediction using lstm

Tags: machine-learning, python, lstm

I am using LSTM model to predict the data traffic in every second of a base station. The dataset is as follows:
[image]

The test and train prediction looks as follows:
[image]

And the RMSE values for train score and test score are 32.54 and 30.03 respectively.
To reduce the RMSE values I have changed the lookback value to 15,20 and 30 but it's not reducing.
Can somebody tell me the reason behind this huge prediction error and some advice on how to correct it? I would love to hear from it.
Thank you.

My code for the LSTM model looks as follows:

````
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)
  
  # reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 10
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
print(trainX.shape)
trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[3], 1))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], testX.shape[3], 1))
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,activation='relu',return_sequences=True,input_shape=(look_back,1)))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.summary()
Xdata_train=[]
Ydata_train=[]

Xdata_train, Ydata_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
Xdata_train = np.reshape(Xdata_train, (Xdata_train.shape[0], Xdata_train.shape[3], 1))

history = model.fit(Xdata_train,Ydata_train,batch_size=1,epochs=20,shuffle=False)
# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)

# invert predictions
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])

# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:,0]))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))
# shift train predictions for plotting
trainPredictPlot = np.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict

# shift test predictions for plotting
testPredictPlot = np.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, :] = testPredict

# plot baseline and predictions
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset))
plt.plot(trainPredictPlot)
plt.plot(testPredictPlot)
plt.xlabel('Time in Seconds')
plt.ylabel('Data Traffic in MB')
plt.legend(['Train','Train Predict','Test Predict'],loc='best')
plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your model is currently **completly underfitting** due to the too deep architecture of your LSTM. To solve your problem, your *first objective* will be to obtain a model that is good on the training data. Then, in a second time, you will search to obtain a model that is good on the validation data.

### Solving the underfitting with RNN-LSTM

Here is what you can do to solve this underfitting problem :

- Remove the second and third LSTM layers. If you only have a single LSTM layer remaining, make sure to turn off *return_sequences* to *False*.
- Lower the number of LSTM neurons in your first layers. Maybe a number between 10 and 20 would be a better choice to start and reduce underfitting.
- Increase the batch size to a more consistent number such as 32, 64 or 128.
- Increase the number of epochs until your performance on the training set is good.
- Scale your input features.

Once you obtain a good score on the training set, you can try to obtain the best score as possible on your validation data.